# AMD version of Google Maps V3 for use with require.js?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, requirejs, js-amd

Has anybody used Googlemaps V3 with something like require.js where it needs to be in AMD version?  Is there one already done somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In require.js you can use the async plugin, then call it like such:

```
define([
    'async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'
], function(){
    //Create your map.
});
```

Comment: Beware, after running the RequireJS optimizer the optimized script will not load google maps API.

Comment: And how do you set the API key like this? `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY_KEY>&sensor=false`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using jQuery.Deferred() and some global variables (not ideal, but I needed it so I could optimize my files using grunt rjs, which didn't work for async):

```
// gmapsDone.js
window._mapsLoaded = $.Deferred();
window.gmapsLoaded = function(data) {
  delete window.gmapsLoaded;
  _mapsLoaded.resolve();
};

define(["http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=gmapsLoaded"], function(gmaps) {
  "use strict";

  return window._mapsLoaded.done;
});
```

Then, to use it:

```
define(["gmapsDone"], function(gmapsDone) {
  function load() {
    // Do something
  }
  gmapsDone(load);
});
```

https://gist.github.com/taktran/5389668

Inspired by http://blog.pixelingene.com/2011/10/using-jquery-dot-deferred-and-requirejs-to-lazy-load-google-maps-api/

Comment: Thaks zlog - it's working - can You take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515964/object-scope-in-javascript-requirejs

Answer (score 2):

I recently helped a friend solve this issue with a take off on the $.Deferred approach mentioned above. This plays nice with the optimizer and doesn't cause multiple script loads.

#### The Module

```
var google_maps_loaded_def = null;

define(['jquery'],function($) {

  if(!google_maps_loaded_def) {

    google_maps_loaded_def = $.Deferred();

    window.google_maps_loaded = function() {
      google_maps_loaded_def.resolve(google.maps);    
    }

    require(['http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=google_maps_loaded'],function(){},function(err) {
      google_maps_loaded_def.reject();
      //throw err; // maybe freak out a little?
    });

  }

  return google_maps_loaded_def.promise();

});
```

Available as a Gist:
https://gist.github.com/MattSurabian/7868115

#### Usage

To Use the above module and take advantage of the fact that the promise resolves with google.maps:

```
    define([ 'app/lib/google-maps-loader' ], function(GoogleMapsLoader){
        GoogleMapsLoader.done(function(GoogleMaps){
            // your google maps code here!
            var geocoder = new GoogleMaps.Geocoder();
        }).fail(function(){ 
            console.error("ERROR: Google maps library failed to load");
        });
    });
```

Alternatively, just reference the `google.maps` object normally

```
    define([ 'app/lib/google-maps-loader' ], function(GoogleMapsLoader){
        GoogleMapsLoader.done(function(){
            // your google maps code here!
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        }).fail(function(){ 
            console.error("ERROR: Google maps library failed to load");
        });
    });
```

I wrote a short blog post about this method here, which may be of some use: [RequireJS Projects and Asynchronously Loading the Google Maps API](http://mattsurabian.github.io/requirejs-projects-and-asynchronously-loading-the-google-maps-api/)

Answer (score 1):

I put together a [Google Maps AMD loader plugin](https://github.com/hamweather/googlemaps-amd), which adds some functionality on top of the async! loader.

```
require.config({
  googlemaps: {
    params: {
      key: 'abcd1234',        // sets api key
      libraries: 'geometry'   // set google libraries
    }
  }
});
require(['googlemaps!'], function(gmaps) {
  // google.maps available as gmaps
  var map = new gmaps.Map('map-canvas');
});
```

Comment: i just yours is the one that I'm  looking for. If I use it on Single page application, is it possible to destroy the `gmaps` you define above. How about clearing the listeners?