# Object scope in javascript (requirejs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm using requireJS with googlemaps.
I'm using plugin to load google maps: https://gist.github.com/taktran/5389668 (google maps api should be loaded with jQuery promise)

I have problem with "this" scope.
Here is my code:

```
//funcs.js file  
  define('myFuncs', ['jquery', 'googleMaps'], function ($, googleMaps) {
      var myFuncs = {
        myVar="true";
        init: function () {
          googleMaps(this.map_init);
        },
        map_init:function () {
          //scripts after loading map
          console.log(this.myVar); //undefined
          console.log(this);//jQuery promise
          console.log(myFuncs.myVar); //true
      }
      return myFuncs;
    });
```

execute:

```
require(['funcs'], function (myFuncs) {
  myFuncs.init();
});
```

How to make this=myFuncs not jQuery promise??

Comment: `this.myVar` -> `myFunds.myVar` . Also, you have a syntax error. Alternatively `function() { }` -> `function() { }.bind(myFuncs)` and keep using `this`.

Comment: Whe I've added googleMaps(this.map_init(this)); this var i ok, but now new google.maps.LatLng(0,0); gives error

Comment: googleMaps(this.map_init.bind(this)); worked - thx